# Word "data"-plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I would like to know if the word "data" is plural or singular? I have looked up some dictionaries but failed to find any relevant information. Thanks!

Comment: Data is like the demonym for all the possible valures some vector or feature may have.

Answer (score 3):

> In terms of Etymology, data is the plural of '***[datum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/datum)***' in Latin. In Latin, data would get plural verb agreement.

However, over time, the frequency of usage of'*datum*' has reduced drastically. Having said this, it is accepted in many places that '*data*' has both a singular and plural existence.

When data is a count noun (items that can be counted), the plural makes sense.

> The data used **were** out of date.

However, when data is treated as a non-count noun (items cannot be counted), the singular makes sense.

> The data used **was** out of date.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/datum),

> Data leads a life of its own quite independent of datum, of which it was originally the plural. It occurs in two constructions: such as a plural noun (like earnings), taking a plural verb and plural modifiers (such as these, many, and a few) but not cardinal numbers, and serving as a referent for plural pronouns (such as they and them); and as an abstract mass noun (like information), taking a singular verb and singular modifiers (such as this, much, and little), and being referred to by a singular pronoun (it). Both constructions are standard. The plural construction is more common in print, evidently because the house style of several publishers mandates it.

And according to [Oxford Dictionaries - Blog](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/04/data-media-two-tricky-latin-plurals-handle/),

> This word is the plural of the Latin noun datum, which literally means ‘something given’. The historical Oxford English Dictionary (OED)’s first recorded meaning (1630) of datum in English is ‘an item of (chiefly numerical) information’, and the first citation is actually for the plural form, data. The singular form, datum, has always been much rarer than the plural in English: there are only 917 instances of this on the OEC, compared with 542,151 for data.

A few good reads you might be interested in:

- http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/04/data-media-two-tricky-latin-plurals-handle/
- https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2010/jul/16/data-plural-singular
- http://www.onlinegrammar.com.au/top-10-grammar-myths-data-is-plural-so-must-take-a-plural-verb/
- https://www.forbes.com/sites/naomirobbins/2012/07/25/is-the-word-data-singular-or-plural/#617fc0575475

**Related Questions**:

- [Data - Singular or Plural (ELU)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/is-data-treated-as-singular-or-plural-in-formal-contexts)
- [Data *'is'* **or** Data *'was'*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23969/should-i-write-all-the-data-is-correct-or-all-the-data-are-correct)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/data), the definition of data is:

> In Latin, data is the plural of datum and, historically and in specialized scientific fields, it is also treated as a plural in English, taking a plural verb, as in the data were collected and classified. In modern non-scientific use, however, it is generally not treated as a plural. Instead, it is treated as a mass noun, similar to a word like information, which takes a singular verb. Sentences such as data was collected over a number of years are now widely accepted in standard English

So, if you are concerned about correct Latin, "the data is" is incorrect and should be replaced with "the *datum* is".

However, the modern usage of the term is much relaxed and you would be correct to use "data" as either singular or plural.

Comment: That's the Oxford Dictionary of English, which is (perhaps confusingly) a completely different dictionary from the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: @snailplane, wow!! had absolutely no idea about this. However, a simple google search wasn't able to clear this confusion. If you could just point towards the difference between the two, I would be happy to change the words.

Comment: There's an explanation of the difference on the [Oxford Dictionaries website](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/news-and-press/oxford-dictionaries-faq).  Oxford Dictionaries is a web version of the Oxford Dictionary of English, along with its American version, the New Oxford American Dictionary; they've chosen to rebrand it as "Oxford Dictionaries" for their website.  The OED is separate and has its own website, which is subscription-based: http://www.oed.com/