# What is the subject of verb "are"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, subject-verb-agreement

> By the time data on whether they met the targets are made public, Mr Trump could be long gone.

i) The verb "are" takes which subject ?
ii) How to understand/ find out the subject in this type of sentence?
iii) what kind of sentence is this and what is the meaning of second clause?

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate question. The OP could not possibly have known to search for a question on the plurality of the word 'data' if they didn't know it could ever be plural. It is the source of confusion, but not the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Are" refers to **data**. Here's the same sentence with parenthesis added:

> By the time data (on whether they met the targets) are made public, Mr Trump could be long gone.

"Data" is technically a plural noun - the singular is *datum* - but it is more commonly used as a singular noun, so while your example is arguably correct, it is unusual and not surprising that you were thrown by it. But if you also treated the detail on what the data is/are on as parenthetical (because that could have been stated in a previous sentence) it makes it more obvious as the subject and noun are brought together.

Comment: Data is "technically" *both* a singular *and* plural noun—as [most dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data) indicate. Saying that it's "technically" only plural is misleading and inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

You ask how to find out what the subject is in such a sentence. It is probably best to start in the middle. They met the targets. That clearly goes together. Probably the whether goes with it. So now we can take that out (another answer suggests putting it into parenthesis to emphasise that. You are now left with only one plausible candidate for the subject, data, as time can hardly be it. The problem now is that there is major argument between English speakers as to whether data is a plural or a singular. This site has had a discussion about this [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23969/should-i-write-all-the-data-is-correct-or-all-the-data-are-correct) which may help. Speaking personally I avoid the word and use data-set instead or re-write the sentence so as to conceal my views as I know that whatever I write it will annoy someone.